# BitBucket hook to not remove approvals on PRs when fast forward merge is committed and pushed

Tags: git, bitbucket

Our repo is currently set to remove any approvals whenever the PR is updated, which means that fast forward merge commits force the developer to track down approvers to re-approve the PR. For structural reasons, approvals can take some time (even days).

If we were to require fast forwards, is there a hook that would instruct BitBucket not to clear existing approvals on this type of commit? Any changes outside of a fast forward would clear the approvals.

It seems as though BB can recognize a FF, so I'm thinking there should be a way to do this.

I've been searching for a while now but haven't found anything related to my goal.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem you are asking about happens when a PR is updated by someone pushing their work to the PR branch. Is this in response to requested changes during review? Do these changes need reviewed and approved before the PR is accepted? But then why would the issue be approved if there are requests for changes? If the PR is approved, it seems to me that the developer shouldn't be pushing new changes to it.

Comment: Is this question about Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, our goal is to not require re-approval of PRs when the update is just a FF.

Comment: @JimRedmond, this is an internally hosted Bitbucket server.

Comment: I suppose one possibility is somehow (on the server side) extracting the items that require a fast forward, and then compare them to the new commit. If there are no other files changed, then approvals wouldn't be cleared.